# How to iterate over an array created by select-object

Tags: powershell

I just feel really stupid right now. I forgot how to iterate over an array created by `Select-Object`, and I can't find a solution.

I have a command like this:

```
$sitepublish = gci "W:\PublishSettings\$remoteIIS" | select FullName,BaseName
```

Which returns objects like this:

```
@{FullName=\\server\wdp$\PublishSettings\xy.PublishSettings; BaseName=xy}
```

How do I know iterate over it to get the `FullName` and the `BaseName` property for each object?

I tried this:

```
$sitepublish.Keys | % {
    Write-Host $_.FullName -fore Blue
    Write-Host $_.BaseName -fore Green
}
```

But it doesn't return anything.

Instead of `.keys` I also tried `.properties`, `.psobject.properties`, `.getenumerator()` and also just the variable without anything else (so just `$sitepublish | % {}`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet:

```
$sitepublish | Foreach-Object {
    Write-Host $_.FullName -fore Blue
    Write-Host $_.BaseName -fore Green
}
```

Comment: I'm already using this, `% {}` is an alias for `foreach-object {}` :)

Comment: You don't have to use the `Keys` property to iterate over it. Give it a try ;-)

Comment: it doesn't work, I already tried it without a property, and now again because you made me insecure. no return

Comment: Which PowerShell version you are using? This works fine for me.

Comment: i got it now. it was a problem of the powershell_ise itself. after restarting it worked. i guess it was because I played around with the `$sitepublish` variable. made it a `[string[]]`, emptied it with `$sitepublish = ""`, made it a `[psobject]`, seems like ISE couldn't handle this, so that's where the error occured. thanks for your help